# Issue in converting the video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, conversion

I'm trying to convert a video of configuration 1080p-Resolution; 18Mps-video bitrate; 30fps to 1080p; 18Mps; 60fps using ffmpeg on windows platform.

I use the command: ffmpeg -i input.avi -r 60 output.avi

Observation: Instead of converting only the frame per second, I observe that the video bit rate also getting reduced to 4Mps.

Where I must have gone wrong? What should I do to convert only the frames per second? Am I missing in the basic understanding of how these video conversion happens?

Comment: Tell about your OS ?

Comment: I have windows 7

Comment: It looks like you are converting a 30 fps video to a 60 fps video. Why do you need to do that?

Comment: If you're trying to speed up the video, [try this instead](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video).

Answer (score 0):

When you try to change any aspect of the video, FFMPEG re-encodes your video, without specifying further options, it selects some default behaviors.  The bitrate is changing based on the default output options for the conversion.

If the output video looks fine, then don't worry about it.

If the output video looks to be of lower quality, you can specify the output quality should be used.  One way to impact output quality is with the -qscale argument ranging between 1 (best) and 31 (worst) quality:

`ffmpeg -i input.avi -r 60 -qscale 1 output.avi`

This will produce a constant high quality video, but with a variable bitrate.

This may actually cause the file size to increase, you can regulate the overall bit rate with the -b:v option, like so:

`ffmpeg -i input.avi -r 60 -b:v 18Mi -bufsize 18Mi output.avi`

This would create a file where each second of video could be up to 18*2^20 bits.  Other bit rates you may be interested in are:

- 18M - 18*10^6 bits per second
- 18MB - 18*8*10^6 bits per second
- 18MiB - 18*8*2^20 bits per second